# From where does the System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll is being referred in my system?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reference, system.componentmodel

I have a C# project that generates `some.dll` and it references a bunch of DLLs, one of them is `System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll` which is found under `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0`.

I built `some.dll` and deployed on a Windows XP system. The application that uses this `some.dll` runs normally. But when I try to look for the `System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll` under `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` on the Windows XP system, I could not find it.

I just want to understand how the application is running properly.

The reason why I want to understand it is, I built the `some.dll` in a different system and deployed on another Windows XP system. When I try to start the application, the application crashes with error:

```
Exception ::Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.resources, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=en-NZ, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference assemblies are used at *compile time*. Usually, as here, to refer to assemblies that are installed as *part* of the .NET Framework. Which will place these assemblies somewhere under either `C:\Windows\Assembly` (for the GAC) or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net`.

It would tend to suggest in this case that the machine with the component missing does not have the correct version of .NET installed.

Comment: I thought that too. But, in the system in which the application was working earlier, if I place the some.dll which was compiled in the second system, the application would give the error again.

Comment: @pasha - note that it refers to an `en-NZ` culture in the error message - so you may be inappropriately referencing/lacking a (human) language specific part of the install.